# AWS Step Function and SNS Notification

Tags: python, amazon-sns, aws-step-functions

Aws Step function , lets say we have a Task with below Retry Logic, it is going to retry for 6 times, after 10 seconds, 1 min, 6 mins, 36 mins, 3.6 hours and finally after 21.6 hours. However, I would like to send out a SNS notification when retry failed after 6 attempts, to take an action and resolve backend issues.

```
{
   "Type":"Task",
   "Resource":"${MyLambda}",
   "End":true,
   "Retry":[
      {
         "ErrorEquals":[
            "States.ALL"
         ],
         "IntervalSeconds":10,
         "MaxAttempts":6,
         "BackoffRate":6
      }
   ]
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to the catch failure and move to the step that sends SNS notification:

```
{
   "Type":"Task",
   "Resource":"${MyLambda}",
   "End":true,
   "Retry":[
      {
         "ErrorEquals":[
            "States.ALL"
         ],
         "IntervalSeconds":10,
         "MaxAttempts":6,
         "BackoffRate":6
      }
   ],
   "Catch": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": ["States.ALL"],
          "Next": "SendSNSNotification"
        }
   ],
},
"SendSNSNotification" {
  "Type": "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::sns:publish",
  "Parameters": {
    "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:ACCOUNT_ID:myTopic",
    "Message": {
      "Input": "Hello from Step Functions!"
    }
  },
  "Next": "NEXT_STATE"
}
```

Catch failure only works after retry attempts.